# PC crash while updating dependencies on composer require command

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am working on symfony 2.8
My composer version is 1.8.6
when I try to install any package , command executes up to updating dependencies and crashes my pc while writing
provider to cache.

I have checked my memory...its set to -1
still it gives out of memory some times.
my xdebug mode is not enabled

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.4.*",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twitter/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
    "lexik/translation-bundle": "3.1.1",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.1.7",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "@stable",
    "imagine/imagine": "dev-master",
    "apy/datagrid-bundle": "@stable",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "~1.8.0",
    "adesigns/calendar-bundle": "@stable",
    "cache/adapter-bundle": "@stable",
    "cache/memcache-adapter": "@stable",
    "cache/memcached-adapter": "@stable",
    "jublonet/codebird-php": "^3.1",
    "elao/error-notifier-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "jaybizzle/crawler-detect": "@stable",
    "rlanvin/php-rrule": "^1.4",
    "eluceo/ical": "^0.11.0",
    "oneup/uploader-bundle": "~1.4",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
    "goodby/csv": "^1.3",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.38",
    "mediafigaro/google-analytics-api-symfony": "~1.21",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
    }
} }
```

presently installing package 
composer require `"mediafigaro/google-analytics-api-symfony"`
command executes properly till:

```
[531.6MiB/170.74s] Writing /home/schandole/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-paragonie$constant-time-encoding.json into cache
```

after this pc gets hang or some time it shows out of memory error or some times process gets killed

{
$free -m
            total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         5925        4239         506         514        1180         979
Swap:        2047           8        2039
}

Comment: `after this pc gets hang or some time it shows out of memory error`
  
  
Sounds like your PC is running out of RAM entirely. Can you check if that's the case?  
If it is there is probably not much to do than to close everything you don't need while running the command.

Comment: No its not the case. Actually we 3 people are working on this. All are facing same problem

Comment: As a hint: you can help Composer if you narrow the dependencies down. For example, if you know you want to use Symfony 2.8.x, set the dependency to `~2.8`- this eases the dependency resolution a lot